# How to ensure all instances are running the same version in Elastic Beanstalk application?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an Elastic Beanstalk application running Docker. During an immutable deploy, Elastic Beanstalk spins up new instances, runs the containers, adds the new instances to the ELB, runs health checks, and then deletes the old instances (my understanding at least).

So, there is a point during the deploy where two instances may be running different version containers. Depending on the difference between the docker images, this tends to cause errors during the deploy.

How can I ensure that the same version is running on all instances in the ELB at any point?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you don't want downtime for your application when you deploy,

You can use EBS blue-green deployment strategy.

1. Clone the environment.
2. Deploy the new version.
3. Swap the environment URLs.